How to fix exploding Coefficients for Lasso Regression
I trid to implement the coordinate descent algorithm for the Lasso Regression (in R) following this post. The only difference is the scaling of the cost function by 1/n according to my text book here which is not freely available. But I also tried the non-scaled version and no difference occured.
Everything works fine if I have N>p but as soon as I get any covariance into my predictors (i.e. p>N or simply simulating multivariate normal data with covariance). My estimated coefficients explode after a few iterations, except when I take lambda large enough to push all coefficients to 0.
I already went over my code a few times and cannot find my mistake. But as Lasso is meant for such cases, there has to be some. I have tried it with different lambdas (a range of suitables lambdas is given in the book), same outcome for the betas - either all 0 or exploding.
Any help in finding my mistake is appreciated.
A minimal example with a plot to show my problem:
# some libraries might be overkill
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)
library(rlist)

RSS <- function(Y, X, beta){
  n <- length(Y)
  return(sapply( 1:length(beta[,1]), function(x){1/n*sum((Y - beta[x,]%*%t(X))^2)} ))
}

set.seed(1234)
n <- 5
p <- 10
lam <- 1
#get the covar matrix
Sigma <- matrix(0.5, nrow = p, ncol = p)
diag(Sigma) <- 1  
mu <- rep(0, p)
X <- mvrnorm(n, mu, Sigma)
# scale X to omit beta0
X <- scale(X)
# simulate data 
beta_true <- rep(c(1,-1,0), each = ceiling(p/3))[1:p]
Y <- beta_true%*%t(X)
beta_est <- Lasso(Y, X, rep(1, length(X[1,])))
rss <- RSS(Y, X, beta_est)
penalty <- lam * rowSums(abs(beta_est))

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:length(rss))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = rss + penalty, color = "Penalty + RSS")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = rss, color = "RSS")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = penalty, color = "Penalty")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Penalty + RSS" = "black", "RSS" = "red", "Penalty" = "blue"), 
                     name = "Legend") + 
  labs(y = NULL, x = "Iteration")

my Lasso Regression function as follows.
soft_threshold <- function(theta, lambda) {
  return(sign(theta) * max(abs(theta) - lambda, 0))
}

Lasso <- function(y, X, lam, starting_coef){
  
  p <- length(starting_coef)
  n <- length(y)
  coef <- matrix(starting_coef, nrow = 1)
  z_j <- 1/n*colSums(X^2) # can calculate outside of loop
  
  t <- 1 # set time step
  # max number of iterations
  while(t<=50){
    
    new_coef <- c() # initialize the new coefs
    
    # do it for all coefs cyclical 
    for(j in 1:p){
      
      
      roh_j <- 1/n * ( y - coef[t,-j] %*% t(X[, -j])) %*% X[,j]
      # the calculation of roh_j splitted up
      #r_ij <- y - coef[t, -j]%*%t(X[,-j])
      #roh_j <- 1/n * sum( r_ij * X[,j] )

      new_beta <- 1/z_j[j] * soft_threshold(roh_j, lam)
      new_coef <- c(new_coef, new_beta)
      
    }
    
    coef <- rbind(coef, new_coef)
    # check if significant change
    if(max(abs(coef[t+1,] - coef[t,])) < 10^-4){
      break
    }
    t <- t+1
    
  }
  
  return(coef)
  
}

